# Which animation or visual queue indicates that there's more content below on mobile

Tags: mobile-application, affordance, microinteractions, perceived-affordance

designing a form on a mobile app. It's not visible within a single screen, yet not long enough to be on a 2nd screen.

My question is, what kind of animation or visual queue can i use to create an affordance that there's more content below. i've seen similar things on desktop like this, but not for mobile.

[image]
Any suggestions and real world examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of a screen that concerns you, or that clearly shows the problem?

Comment: Put the submit button below, so that users have to scroll and see the whole form before seeing it. As a user, it would not be a problem to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an animation for this as long as you make sure to avoid the [Illusion of Completeness](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/illusion-of-completeness/). If users have the impression that there is more content *down there* then they will eagerly scroll. Complementary, if users have the impression that they're already looking at the whole thing, they might be discouraged from scrolling.

You can read more about this topic in [The Fold Manifesto](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/page-fold-manifesto/) of the Nielsen Norman Group. Note, that there are also voices out there who argue that users have evolved and that [the fold no longer exists](https://medium.com/rareview/the-above-the-fold-myth-f0f93b1b9875). The linked article states that users will eagerly scroll anyway, often even before the page has fully loaded.

No matter which side of the discussion you're on, you're probably fine without an explicit hint or animation. This would only draw the attention away from where it should be: the actual content.